# How to map an enum to another enum in typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums, casting

I want to map one object's property that has an enum type to another object's property that is other enum type.

I've tried with `type1.a as Enum2` or `Enum2[type1.a]` with no success.

Here is my simplified code problem:

```js
enum Enum1 {
  N = 0,
  A = 1,
  B = 2
}

enum Enum2 {
  A = 1,
  B = 2
}

interface Type1 {
  a: Enum1;
}

interface Type2 {
  a: Enum2;
}

const type1: Type1 = {
  a: Enum1.A
};

const type2: Type2 = {
  a: type1.a
};
```

[try it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Enum1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20N%20%3D%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20A%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20B%20%3D%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20Enum2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20A%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20B%20%3D%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Type1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20Enum1%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Type2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20Enum2%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20type1%3A%20Type1%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20Enum1.A%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20type2%3A%20Type2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20type1.a%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Throws the error:

```
Type 'Enum1' is not assignable to type 'Enum2'.
(property) Type2.a: Enum2
```

Comment: I'm not sure at 100%, but the compiler correctly refuses the cast: what should happen when the `a` field becomes "N"? the Enum2 does not allow "N" as possible value. However, if you really want to cast two incompatible types, you may cast one to "any" first, then follow a second cast to Enum2...at your own risk!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast the `type1.a` prop to `Enum2`. To do this you need to use a "Type Predicate".

Here is an example with your code:

```
enum Enum1 {
  N = 0,
  A = 1,
  B = 2
}

enum Enum2 {
  A = 1,
  B = 2
}

interface Type1 {
  a: Enum1;
}

interface Type2 {
  a: Enum2;
}

const type1: Type1 = {
  a: Enum1.N
};

function isEnum2(value: any): value is Enum2 {
  let isEnum2 = false;

  for (let key in Enum2) {
    if (Enum2[key] === value) {
      isEnum2 = true;
    }
  }

  return isEnum2;
}

if (isEnum2(type1.a)) {
  const type2: Type2 = {
    a: type1.a
  };
}
```

[try it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEEYoG8CwAoKUByUC8UADADQZYCC+UCpmUAQlQEwYC+GGoks8TKZUSgRoDGBFunboMASxAAXYACcAZgEMAxsCgAVAJ4AHYEjR01ALh6QEAbjYd0cxas3b9RvqawWrEJnckHDQB7EABneSh5Q2NLd2MqLygfOGsAOmw2AIwVMBANeRlQqBkw1L8ACgA3NQAbMGBLNRA9AEpLGvrtUt9PAVrgSNLyvgJ1WrDgbLoVYKUoCoHIgGtgPRKQXtb+OiwZFQWRgG1VvQBdfDwCTobtpKw9st4qeSUGgIeoKSwpASVBsBKTbDXgBX6OA4VEGQJgVaJGBBpNStO4CELhSLw4BMOIxUY7T4+LGItQCVhgoA)

When the `isEnum2` function is used in the `if` block the prop `type1.a` becomes of type `Enum2` inside that `if` block only.

**Note:** you could replace the content in the `isEnum2` using `for..in` loop if you are using ES2017 or higher using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
return Object.values(Enum2).includes(value);
```

[try it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEEYoG8BQUoDkoF4oAYAadKAQVygWIwCEKAmVAX1VVElnnpRPLypJ08jFqgCWIAC7AATgDMAhgGNgUACoBPAA7AkaDAoBcnSAgDczVhOnzlqzTu76oRkxHoXRSgPYgAzpJQktq6xg66FM6ucKYAdJjMFqhyYCBKkmK+UGJ+Me4AFABuCgA2YMDGCiAaAJTGxWWqOW5OJDLAkmAyIFAA8gBGAFbA6bEN5X75efQ1sRJKZQAmwJPjwDWeVnJQ+TnT+cE6CLEKNTU8GD7+gYfA9GEh3HjOBsa3xwokTEmXvgFQ7HcxmmFFu9BOPygVz83hKwFiJW8AHN8oCZpsgA)

[More info about Type Predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)