# How can I reference a enum in another enum

Tags: typescript

I have this code in `typescript`:

```
export enum A {
  name = 'A',
}

export enum Names {
  nameA = A.name,  // ERROR
  nameB = 'B',
}
```

The error I get is `Computed values are not permitted in an enum with string valued members.` on the line `nameA = A.name`. How can I assign the value from a different enum?

Comment: have a look at a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374588/how-to-map-an-enum-to-another-enum-in-typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. You'd just have to define it again.

```
export enum A {
  name = 'A',
}

export enum Names {
  nameA = 'A',
  nameB = 'B',
}
```