# Transform one enum to another enum

Tags: typescript, enums

Is there a way for transforming enums in Typescript?
For example. I have an original enum

```
enum original {
  VALUE_1
  VALUE_2
}
```

I'd like to transform uppercase to lowercase, as

```
enum original {
  value_1
  value_2
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: this could help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374588/how-to-map-an-enum-to-another-enum-in-typescript

Comment: The example code is invalid TypeScript; could you fix it?  What are you doing with the enums?  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NalD0w) to transform the keys of any object, but enums have some specific features that will not be preserved by such a transformation.  If you could give a [mcve] including showing the intended use case, it would be helpful.

Comment: @jcalz Thx. There was typos with enums.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks again. Your example is what I really need. )))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can use write a function called `lowercaseKeys()` to transform the keys of any object to lowercase, and then [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that such a function returns a strongly typed result.  The return type involves [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) to make a mapped type where the string [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) keys into their lowercase counterparts via the [`Lowercase` intrinsic string manipulation type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#lowercasestringtype):

```
function lowercaseKeys<T extends object>(obj: T): { 
  [K in keyof T as K extends string ? Lowercase<K> : K]: T[K] 
} {
    return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k.toLowerCase(), v])
    ) as any;
}
```

Again, this should work for any object:

```
const example = lowercaseKeys({ STR: "hello", NUM: Math.PI });
/* const example: {
    str: string;
    num: number;
} */
console.log(example.num.toFixed(2)); // 3.14
```

You can see that at runtime, `example` has keys named `str` and `num`, and the compiler is aware of this.

---

An `enum` is also an object with keys and values, so you can transform it the same way:

```
const LowercaseEnum = lowercaseKeys(OriginalEnum);
/* const LowercaseEnum: {
    [x: number]: string;
    readonly value_1: OriginalEnum.VALUE_1;
    readonly value_2: OriginalEnum.VALUE_2;
} */
console.log(LowercaseEnum.value_1.toFixed()); // "0"
console.log(LowercaseEnum.value_2.toFixed()); // "1"
```

Hooray!

---

Well, that's great as far as it goes.  But note that an `enum` also has some special features apart from a regular object.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66864086/2887218) for a more in-depth description of this differences.)  For example, the name of an `enum` can also be used as a *type* corresponding to the union of its values:

```
interface Okay {
    e: OriginalEnum;
}
```

But `LowercaseEnum` is just an object and was not declared as an `enum`; there is no type named `LowercaseEnum`:

```
interface Oops {
    e: LowercaseEnum; // error
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // 'LowercaseEnum' refers to a value, 
    // but is being used as a type here.
}
```

If you want such a type, you must make it:

```
type LowercaseEnum = OriginalEnum; // same values, so same type
```

Another difference is that a true numeric `enum` like `OriginalEnum` has a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings), where if `OriginalEnum.VALUE_1` is `0`, then `OriginalEnum[0]` is `"VALUE_1"`:

```
console.log(OriginalEnum[0]); // "VALUE_1" as expected
```

But the transformed version doesn't have a useful reverse mapping, because only its keys have been changed; its values are untouched:

```
console.log(LowercaseEnum[0]); // still "VALUE_1", unexpected?
```

So, please be careful when using something like `LowercaseEnum`: while there are similarities, it's not a true `enum`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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)